# Wifi connectivity on a virtual machine while it is not working on the parent machine

Tags: wireless-networking, virtual-machine

I am having wifi connectivity issues on my Windows 8 laptop. I am thinking to install windows 7 as a VM using virtualbox. Will the wifi connection work in the VM (win 7) while it has connection issues in the base machine(win 8)? Please advise.

Thanks
Srinivas

Comment: You're asking us to form an opinion or prognosis about problems that aren't being described to us at all. Telling using you have "connectivity issues" is about as vague as it is possible to be.

Comment: I mentioned it to specify the reason behind why i am installing windows 7. Other than that i am good with Win 8.

Comment: VMs usually use a bridge, not the hardware itself. You could try to give it control of the hardware (I think there is an option for this in VBox at least) and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% certain that your Wi-Fi issues are Windows-8 specific and should go away with Windows-7, using Virtualbox or other virtualization software with pass-through for the Wi-Fi interface will probably work.

Nobody can tell you anything more specific since you have not provided any details about the nature of your Wi-Fi issues.